# I can't edit a object in an array, ng-model doesn't change with ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am making a movie library. I use ng-repeat to show the movies and, for each movie there is a button to edit it and another one to remove it. The remove button works just fine, but the edit button doesn't. 
It should open a panel and fill it with the movie data, but it only opens the panel with the first value I defined for the index.

```
button
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil small btnEdit" ng-click="i =(movies.indexOf(movie));"></i>

input
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" id="title" ng-model="movies[i].title">
```

the whole code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/victoorns/mwgcnsno/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller's $scope property 'i' is being hidden via the rules behind scope inheritance. Ng-repeat creates its own isolate scope and since 'i' is a primitive (its just an integer), 'i' is only being set on that child $scope, as opposed to the main parent controller's scope.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" id="title" 
       ng-model="movies[selected.movieIndex].title">

<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil small btnEdit" 
   ng-click="selected.movieIndex =(movies.indexOf(movie));"></i>
```

Heres an updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mwgcnsno/3/).

Notice how I am using an object (selected.movieIndex) so that is correctly updating the right property.

Heres more on understanding the exact behavior going on with the scope [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Answer (score 0):

Approach is putting too much business logic in the view.

Pass whole object back to controller when you do things like this. Then do any splicing, copying etc in controller:

Simplified example:

```
<div ng-repeat="movie in movies">
  <button ng-click="edit(movie)">
  <button ng-click="delete(movie)">
</div>
```

In controller:

```
  $scope.delete = function(movie){
    var idx = $scope.movies.indexOf(movie);
    if(idx !=-1){      
       $scope.movies.splice(idx,1)
    }
  }

  $scope.edit = function(movie){
     $scope.selectedMovie = movie;
  }
```

Also get rid of all the jQuery and get rid of bootstrap.js and replace with angular-ui-bootstrap